# Using jQuery, AJAX, PHP to delete row in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, sql-delete

**Edit:**
As per solution provided in the comments below.
**The nothing happening in the Database**
The solution was a simple refresh of the page as I previously had the delete.php file in a different directory (so the code worked fine... it was just a case of mistaken identity - it's always the littlest things).

**The nothing happening on the page**
The solution was giving the parent <div> a unique id (the same as the delete-button/image - 1) and then under the ajax-function in my jQuery.js file adding...

```
success: function() {
    $('#'.concat(id)).remove();
}
```

Thank you to **@SikanderNawaz**

**End Edit**

I'm trying to delete a row in my Database by using jQuery, AJAX and PHP, and my code, should be, but is not working.
I click the delete-button, but nothing happens, on the page or in the Database.

Where did I go wrong?
Hope someone here can help.

**Database**

```
------------------
| id | link      |
------------------
| 1  | image.jpg |
------------------
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <button type="button" name="delete" id="delete" class="some stylings" value="1"><h6><b>X</b></h6></button>
    <img src="images/image.jpg" />
    ...
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
</body>
```

**jQuery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#delete').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).val(); // tested and returns 1 (see button value)
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function() {
                $('#'.concat(id)).remove();
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
    
    require ("connection.php");
    
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        
        try {
            
            $sql = 
            "
            DELETE FROM test
            
            WHERE
                id = ?
            ";
            
            $prepareTest = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $prepareTest->execute([$id]);
            
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            
            file_put_contents('../error/e.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
            
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: did you check your network tab? what error are you getting there?

Comment: kindly check network tab or console of your browser and show us what error is it throwing ?

Comment: yes... there is no error showing (from the connection.php or otherwise.... just nothing is happening when I click the delete-button - would have like to have shown connection.php too, just in case, but it said there was to much code)

Comment: hmmm.. it shows a 404 error... can't find delete.php - hang on... I'll look into it... if it is that simple I'm going to cry :) - but it should fond it since it's all in the same folder

Comment: nope... now I got it to show a 200-success message - it found the delete.php successfully but still nothing is happening - on the page or in the Database... so still not working... Edit: (forgot to refresh the page from wwhen I had delete.php in a separate folder)

Comment: return : $e->getMessage()  and cosole.log the returend result in ajax call back : success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }

Comment: @SikanderNawaz it shows an error: <empty string>

Comment: this is complete error message "<empty string> " ? , pls paste full error message

Comment: @SikanderNawaz sorry... shouldn't have called it an error message... in console-view it just say <empty string> - and then refers to the line data: {id:id}

Comment: @SikanderNawaz also now it deletes the row... but I have to refresh the page to see it gone...

Comment: $('#id).remove(); use this to remove.  #id is the id  of the element , like if you have <div id ='1'>content to be removed </div> you can remove the whole div  or any element same way

Comment: @SikanderNawaz thank you - write it as $('#'.concat(id)).remove(); for multiple instances and post it as the answer and I will mark it as such :) - again thank you... it's always the littles oversights that cost you hours of troubleshooting :)

Comment: glad  i could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using JS/ Ajax always use console.log for logging the data and errors and  spot the errors in Networks tabs as well for any db related errors  and manage your debugging with data being dumped at each step of to spot the issue the error is coming from.